# Parse format of value from client to server in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodeJS app

I'm trying to send the user-agent value that I got from the client side using `navigator.userAgent` to the server side using ajax.

**PS : I know I can access the user-agent from the server. I am aware of that. I am doing this for a certain purpose.**

As follows :

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async() => {
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/UA/send/',
                    data: navigator.userAgent })             
});
```

In my nodeJS server, I am reading it like that:

```
app.post('/UA/send', function(req, res) 
{  
        console.log(req.body));
});
```

This returns

```
{ 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36': '' }
```

I added  `alert(navigator.userAgent);` to my javascript code and I got this :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
```

Why am I getting it in the following format to the server side? And how could I parse and read it?

Comment: Try setting the AJAX data to `data: { 'userAgent': navigator.userAgent }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting a JSON using `$.ajax`, you have to use `JSON.stringify`, and `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header, otherwise you're sending form data. In your example you were sending the user agent as key, and no value.

That's why the posted object looked like: `{ [userAgentValue]: ''}`

Use this for posting a JSON.

```
 $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/UA/send/',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      data: JSON.stringify({ userAgent: navigator.userAgent })
 });
```

With the correct body parser on your server:

```javascript
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Now you will receive:

```
{ userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36' }
```

---

If you're not trying to post a JSON, and you're using: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'/UA/send/',
     data: { userAgent: navigator.userAgent }
 });
```

And on your server:

```javascript
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```